# xmlstarlet delete node with range

Tags: xml, range, xmlstarlet

I'd to know how to delete a node with range using the command below.

single node delete works fine:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -d '//job/input/audio_selector[2]' profile.xml
```

How to achieve this if I want to delete a node with range.

sample delete a node audio_selector from range 2 to 20:

Comment: Your current xpath is deleting the `audio_selector` based on position; it's deleting the second `audio_selector`. Is this what you really want or do you want to base it on the value of `audio_selector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to delete the `audio_selector` based on position, try:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -d '//job/input/audio_selector[position() >= 2 and 20 >= position()]' profile.xml
```

If you're trying to delete the `audio_selector` based on value, try:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -d '//job/input/audio_selector[number() >= 2 and 20 >= number()]' profile.xml
```